# Python class w/ Telnet interface to memcached

Tags: python, networking

I haven't had anyone help me out with code review, etc, so I thought I'd post a Python class I put together for interfacing with Telnet to get information from a memcached server.

```
import re, telnetlib

class MemcachedStats:

    _client = None

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port='11211'):
        self._host = host
        self._port = port

    @property
    def client(self):
        if self._client is None:
            self._client = telnetlib.Telnet(self._host, self._port)
        return self._client

    def key_details(self, sort=True):
        ' Return a list of tuples containing keys and details '
        keys = []
        slab_ids = self.slab_ids()
        for id in slab_ids:
            self.client.write("stats cachedump %s 100\n" % id)
            response = self.client.read_until('END')
            keys.extend(re.findall('ITEM (.*) \[(.*); (.*)\]', response))
        if sort:
            return sorted(keys)
        return keys

    def keys(self, sort=True):
        ' Return a list of keys in use '
        return [key[0] for key in self.key_details(sort=sort)]

    def slab_ids(self):
        ' Return a list of slab ids in use '
        self.client.write("stats items\n")
        response = self.client.read_until('END')
        return re.findall('STAT items:(.*):number', response)

    def stats(self):
        ' Return a dict containing memcached stats '
        self.client.write("stats\n")
        response = self.client.read_until('END')
        return dict(re.findall("STAT (.*) (.*)\r", response))
```

This is also up on [GitHub](https://github.com/dlrust/python-memcached-stats/blob/master/src/memcached_stats.py).

I would love some feedback on:

- Organization
- Better ways of accomplishing the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern

```
self.client.write("some command\n")
response = self.client.read_until('END')
```

appears three times in your code. I think this is often enough to warrant refactoring it into its own method like this:

```
def command(self, cmd):
    self.client.write("%s\n" % cmd)
    return self.client.read_until('END')
```

---

In `key_details` you're using `extend` to build up a list. However it's more pythonic to use list comprehensions than building up a list imperatively. Thus I'd recommend using the following list comprehension:

```
regex = 'ITEM (.*) \[(.*); (.*)\]'
cmd = "stats cachedump %s 100"
keys = [key for id in slab_ids for key in re.findall(regex, command(cmd % id))]
```

---

Afterwards you do this:

```
if sort:
    return sorted(keys)
return keys
```

Now this might be a matter of opinion, but I'd rather write this using an `else`:

```
if sort:
    return sorted(keys)
else:
    return keys
```

I think this is optically more pleasing as both `return`s are indented at the same level. It also makes it immediately obviously that the second `return` is what happens if the `if` condition is false.

Comment: thanks! I've incorporated some of these into the code on github. I also added precompiled versions of the regex into the class

Comment: Also, as far as the list comprehension goes. Since `re.findall(regex, command(cmd % id))` can return multiple items, I am using extend. Is there a way to build a list that extends itself vs item by item building?

Comment: @dlrust: Yes, of course, you need to add another `for` in the list comprehension to get a flat list. I actually meant to do that, but forgot somehow.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works `keys = [j for i in [self._key_regex.findall(self.command(cmd % id)) for id in self.slab_ids()] for j in i]`

Comment: @lrust: By using an inner list like that, you need one more `for` than you would otherwise. Does `[key for id in slab_ids for key in self._key_regex.findall(self.command(cmd % id))]` not work for you?